# Conditionally count foreign fields in collection with Mongo aggregations

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, aggregation-framework

A `Post` may have many responses. The `Response` has a `type` field of values `'like'` or `'dislike'`.

I want to write an aggregation that fetches me 50 random posts and their like and dislike counts.

Currently, I can fetch the random posts and lists of their respective responses. But I want to count how many of those responses have `type` of `'like'`, and how many have `type` of `'dislike'`.

What I have is:

```
Post.aggregate([
  { $sample: { size: 50 } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'responses',
      localField: '_id',
      foreignField: 'post',
      as: 'responses',
    },
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      responsesCount: {
        total: { $size: '$responses' }
        like: { $size: '...' }, // get size if response.type === 'like'
        dislike: { $size: '...' }  // get size if response.type === 'dislike'
      },
    },
  },
]);
```

Comment: If this can't be done in a single aggregation, do I do a 'for each' and get the number of responses for each post?

Comment: Something like `like: { $size: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$responses",
               cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.type", "like" ] }
            }
         } }` should work.

Comment: Perfecto! Thanks a lot.